# Android on "<" key up listener on an edit text?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-edittext, onkeydown

I'm trying to make a function for when the "<"/less than key is pressed, but i cant seem to get it correctly. I tried to add `onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent event)` with Log, so that it would log everytime the "<" key was pressed but no matter what nothing is logged. I set the on key listener on my edit text but it doesnt work. Help Please. Is there anything i must add?

```
postingET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postInput); postingET.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
   @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    Log.i("LOL", String.valueOf(view));
    return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
postingET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change log to

```
Log.i("LOL", postingET.getText().toString());
```

Comment: The thing is it only logs when i press keys such as back arrow and enter, not when i press any key.